# Select Units Sold and Total Units Sold from a Sales record table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Select Units Sold and Total Units Sold from a Sales record table using.

When I use this Query, I can get the Units Sold for '2016-04-14'

```
SELECT salesrecord.itemID, salesrecord.itemname, 
   SUM(salesrecord.itemunits) AS `Units Sold` , 
   SUM(salesrecord.itemunits)
WHERE `date`='2016-04-14' 
GROUP BY salesrecord.itemname
```

And When I Use this query, I can get the Total units Sold till date

```
SELECT salesrecord.itemID, salesrecord.itemname, 
   SUM(salesrecord.itemunits) AS `Total Units Sold` , 
   SUM(salesrecord.itemunits) 
WHERE `date`<='2016-04-14' 
GROUP BY salesrecord.itemname
```

What I will like to do is to get both "Units Sold" And "Total Units Sold" on a single table as shown in image attached

[image: My Database]

[image: My Expected Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *conditional aggregate* using `CASE`:

```
SELECT sr.itemID, sr.itemname,
   SUM(sr.itemunits) AS "Total Units Sold", 
   SUM(CASE WHEN date='2016-04-14' THEN sr.itemunits END) AS "Units Sold"
FROM salesrecord AS sr
WHERE date <= '2016-04-14'
GROUP BY sr.itemID, sr.itemname
```

I used a table-alias `sr` which improves readability.

And I added `sr.itemID` to `GROUP BY`, which is compliant with Standard SQL (and the latest version of MySQL)

Comment: Thanks Alot on the SQL Query. It works perfectly on my MySQL and gives the required result . But it does not work in VB.net it gives an error

Comment: @Smarton That looks like an entirely different issue to me. If the query "works perfectly" in MySQL for you, that means your original problem has been solved. How to run the query from a specific environment, like VB.NET, should be a separate question (and possibly not on this site, I suspect).

Comment: Please Here is my VB.Net version of the query                                                                 sql = "SELECT sr.itemcode, sr.itemname,  SUM(CASE WHEN sr.transdate='4/14/2016' THEN sr.temunits] END) AS [Units Sold], " & _
                    "SUM(sr.itemunits) AS [Total Units Sold] " & _
                  "FROM [tblINV_SalesRecord] AS sr WHERE sr.transdate <= '4/14/2016' GROUP BY sr.itemcode, sr.itemname"

Comment: The brackets are not balanced.  (And they are not MySQL syntax.)

Comment: Please Can you point my to how to balance the brackets